# how to turn off warning

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

This function that performs random apportionment works

```
Apal[v_, s_] := 
  Module[{vv = v, ss = s}, 
    p = vv/Total[vv]; (*probability to draw an object*)
    r = Range[Length[vv]]; (* nomber og groups *)
    rc = RandomChoice[p -> r, ss];(* give an object to a group at each draw *)
    Counts[rc] (* count of the number of objects *)
      ns = r /. Counts[rc]
      (* extraction in increasing order of the number of object for each group *)
  ]
```

as shown by

```
Apal[{12, 34, 13, 53, 67, 86, 44}, 128]
```

and

```
Total[Apal[{12, 34, 13, 53, 67, 86, 44}, 128]
```

which gives always 128.

But it prints some warnings

```
Set::write: Tag Times in <|5->26,6->32,4->26,2->17,7->16,1->6,3->5|> {6,18,31,38,58} is Protected.
```

I wonder where is my mistake and if there are no how to turn off the warnings.

Comment: Missing ; after first Counts[rc]

Comment: @CarlWoll's answer should be most useful to you and you should consider changing your question. However, if you ever do need to turn of warning messages, you can use `Off` or `Quiet`. For example `Off[Set::write]` will turn off all `Set::write` messages, wich would be a very bad idea, though.

Comment: The 1st `Counts[rc]` should be removed. The value it returns is never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a simple syntax error. However, it would be nice to have an easy method to find the syntax error. One idea is to use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint):

```
TracePrint[Apal[{12,34,13,53,67,86,44}, 128], _Set]
```

> vv$165781=Unevaluated[{12,34,13,53,67,86,44}]
>
> vv$165781={12,34,13,53,67,86,44}
>
> ss$165781=Unevaluated[128]
>
> ss$165781=128
>
> p=vv\$165781/Total[vv\$165781]
>
> p={4/103,34/309,13/309,53/309,67/309,86/309,44/309}
>
> r=Range[Length[vv$165781]]
>
> r={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
>
> rc=RandomChoice[p->r,ss$165781]
>
> rc={5,4,4,5,6,5,1,6,6,5,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,7,6,4,7,6,1,7,7,7,7,6,7,5,6,6,5,5,1,2,7,4,7,4,5,7,5,7,3,7,5,4,7,6,6,4,4,5,4,4,6,7,6,2,7,5,4,6,5,4,2,7,2,6,5,5,6,7,6,6,6,6,5,5,6,7,7,6,5,7,4,6,2,5,5,6,5,6,4,3,6,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,4,5,7,7,7,2,5,4,6,6,6,6,7,5,7,6,6,6,5,4,5,3,7,6}
>
> Counts[rc] ns=r/. Counts[rc]
>
> Counts[rc] ns={3,6,4,21,29,39,26}
>
> Set::write: Tag Times in <|5->29,4->21,6->39,1->3,3->4,7->26,2->6|> ns is Protected.
>
> {3, 6, 4, 21, 29, 39, 26}

As you can see in the [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) output, the message is generated because of the line:

```
Counts[rc] nc = ...
```

A couple other ideas. One is to print the stack when a message occurs:

```
TracePrint[
    Apal[{12,34,13,53,67,86,44}, 128],
    _Message,
    TraceAction->(Print[Stack[_][[-3]]]&)
]
```

> Counts[rc] ns={7,12,5,16,25,40,23}
>
> Set::write: Tag Times in <|4->16,6->40,7->23,5->25,1->7,2->12,3->5|> ns is Protected.
>
> {7, 12, 5, 16, 25, 40, 23}

Another is to just click on the ... to the left of the message, and then click on "Show Stack Trace". You will see the problematic `Set` expression in the stack trace.